# make bash run a command from inside a function while running a container

Tags: bash, shell, nginx, docker

I have an interesting problem that I can't seem to find an answer to. I am creating a bash script that will allow myself and other developers I work with to auto create docker images, and containers that run NginX and create webservers. I have everything running just fine, I can run a single line and it will do everything needed. The problem comes in when I want to be able to exit the Docker container from within the bash script.
A quick example of what I am talking about is...

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo docker run --name $1 -i -p $2 -t $3
```

Obvioulsy that is an extremely simplistic example, but what it would do is start a new docker container name whatever they want, passing whatever ports they decide, and using whatever image they want.

The real problem comes when I want to exit out of that docker container. I can't just add an "exit 13" to the bash file, since it will not run until after the docker run command stops, which it won't becuase I can't exit from it.

If that docker container did nothing other than start a terminal session in the docker container, how would I go about having my bash script force the docker container to exit?

I know I can manually type "exit 13" in the terminal prompt in the docker container, but I want to have my bash script that created the docker container exit it.

I am so beyond lost as to how this would be possible, if it even is. The way I see it the bash script can't run the next command until the previous command stops, but the previous command can't stop  unless I stop it. Seems like a chicken vs egg problem, but I am hoping someone has found a way to make something like this work. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You run `docker` in the background, at which point the question just becomes *when* do you want to kill the `docker` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use -d option with docker run

`sudo docker run -d --name $1 -i -p $2 -t $3`

`-d, --detach => Run container in background and print container ID`

when you are done kill conatainer by

`docker kill $1`

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew there had to be some option to make it run in the background, but I couldn't find it. Thank you!!